# Undefined variable: entry Laravel 5.4 Passing data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

At the moment I am trying to pass a value of a variable that is $entry from my EntryController to the view that allows me to view the entry depending on the person who is logged in. The database should only retrieve the entry of the user who is logged in. When I run the page, this error appears:

Undefined variable: entry

Here is part of the entry blade file (viewentry.blade.php):

```
<div class="row">
        @foreach ($entry as $entries)

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <strong>Image:</strong>
              {{ $entries->image }}
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <strong>Title:</strong>
              {{ $entries->title }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Description:</strong>
                {{ $entries->description }}
            </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
```

The method to display the entry in the controller (EntryController.php):

```
  public function showUpload(Entries $entry)
  {
    $entry = Entries::with('entrys')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('viewentry', compact('entry'));
  }
```

I'm not sure why this error is coming up as I can't see anything wrong with the code above. Has anyone had this problem before?, If so how can it be solved?

Comment: Are you using `$entry` variable in correct file ?

Comment: Try `Entries::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();`

Comment: Yeah I am, definitely in the right file "viewentry"

Comment: Try this `public function showUpload()` without parameter !!

Comment: Arman Momeni - Tried that but still appears with $entry variable error

Comment: Tried all suggestions but still appears with the same error

Comment: can you add `dd($entry);` before return statment may be because there is no Entries for the given user ID !!

Comment: Still comes up with the same user, the error is from the blade file, but I can't see anywhere in the controller that is causing the error on the blade page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
<div class="row">
       @if(isset($entry) && !empty($entry))
        @foreach ($entry as $entries)

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <strong>Image:</strong>
              {{ $entries->image }}
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <strong>Title:</strong>
              {{ $entries->title }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Description:</strong>
                {{ $entries->description }}
            </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: @footballgeek Gald to help !!! and if my answer is your solution then please upvote to my answer